# Is there a benefit to using multiple font file type sources when declaring a font-face?

Tags: css, cross-browser, font-face

I see a chunk of code declared as such:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'SourceCodePro-Regular';
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
    font-stretch: normal;
    src: local('SourceCodePro-Regular'),     
         url('assets/fonts/EOT/SourceCodePro-Regular.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/WOFF2/TTF/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('assets/fonts/WOFF/OTF/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf.woff') format('woff'),
         url('assets/fonts/OTF/SourceCodePro-Regular.otf') format('opentype'),
         url('assets/fonts/TTF/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Is there a benefit to having a bunch of different sources for this? ie. is there any benefit to requiring `truetype`, `opentype`, `woff`, `woff2`and `embedded-opentype`, or is there a source type that will work for everything?

I assume this is for a fallback, but the documentation doesn't really talk about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

Comment: Yes, it is for a fallback. The compatibility chart on that page does mention, for instance, that WOFF support has been around for a while and WOFF2 support is relatively new. Not sure what else there is to say.

Comment: Ah, cool. Thanks @Morpheus that's a helpful resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different file types are for different browsers. 
Here is a nice overview:

[image]

Source: [CreativeMarket](https://creativemarket.com/blog/the-missing-guide-to-font-formats)

Answer (score 0):

> I assume this is for a fallback,

It is (more or less anyway, fallback implies a good font format and not so good ones that aren't as well supported rather than a mix of font formats that have different levels of support).

> but the documentation doesn't really talk about this

It does. From the page you link to:

[image: Browser compatibility]